# Is directory on external hard drive?

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi

I am wondering how to check if a directory (on my RaspberryPi) is on an external drive or not.

I think I mounted my WD MyPassport correctly, and was able to write to it via /media/pi/MyPassport.  However, something happened and it created a `MyPassport1` folder, which seemed to actually be the external drive. So I have `/media/pi/MyPassport` and `/media/pi/MyPassport1` when the external is connected.

I removed my external drive and still can see (and access/read/write) to `/media/pi/MyPassport`...so something happened that moved the external directory, and created `/media/pi/MyPassport` locally.

I'd like to include in the script I have that copies data to `MyPassport` to first check if `/media/pi/MyPassport` is indeed on an external drive, before copying.

Is that possible?

Edit: I know, now, that the external drive is called `.../MyPassport1`, so could just see if that directory exists, then keep copying...but I'm asking more generally, is there a way to check if a directory is indeed an external drive connected via USB?

Comment: What is the output of `df -h /media/pi/Passport1`, when USB  is mounted.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv - The filesystem is `/dev/sda1`. When I run that command on `/media/pi/"My Passport"`, it's `/dev/root`. I have been learning about Unix and see that `sda1` refers to an external drive, correct? (I know `/dev/root` is the root file system, aka local).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simple, if you  use the command `df -h folder_name`, it will show you the filesystem. e.g.

I have drives mounted in `/mnt/xxx`, folder, if I use command

```
df -h /mnt
/dev/sda1        96G   81G   11G  89% /
```

because `/dev/sda1`  is mounted on `/` folder, and `mnt`, is a directory inside it.

```
df -h /mnt/uuid
/dev/sda5        98G   57G   42G  58% /mnt/uuid
```

So, in your script you can use:

```
if [ "$(df -h /media/pi/MyPassport | grep -o /media/pi/USB)" = "/media/pi/USB" ]
then
echo "USB is mounted"
else
echo "USB is not mounted"
copy....
fi
```

You can also reduce the `if` statement to:

```
if [ "$(df -h /media/pi/MyPassport | grep -o /media/pi/USB)" ]
```

As it will check the exit status.

Comment: Thanks for the great detail! As I commented, the external drive filesystem is showing `/dev/sda1`, so am I correct in thinking that it means, **explicitly** that it's an external drive?  (because `/dev/root` is explicitly the local filesystem, correct?)

Comment: @BruceWayne That is right.

Answer (score 1):

You can check where the device is mounted using the command 'df -h' . Then you can navigate to that folder and access the contents of that device.