# How do I find which disk/partition current directory is on?

Tags: shell

I can print current directory using `pwd`, but this gives me the path I navigated to get to where I am.
I need to know which disk/partition current directory is on.

For example, if I create symlink `user@pc:~$ ln -s /media/HD1 hard_disk` and then navigate to `~/hard_disk` and run `pwd` it will print `/home/user/hard_disk`.

I would like to get the actual path I'm currently on or better just the actual filesystem I'm currently on, which corresponds to one in `df`.

Comment: What should the output be for a filesystem that does not live on a partition? What should the output be for a union filesystem that is the union of multiple different filesystems that may live on different partitions (or no partitions at all)?

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508420/255251

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine what device a directory is located on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128471/determine-what-device-a-directory-is-located-on) or [How do I find on which physical device a folder is located?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11311/22142) etc... plenty of duplicates but nobody wants to search. Nobody.

Comment: @don_crissti The duplicate answers do not mention `pwd -P`, but ok.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`pwd -P` will give you the physical directory you are in, i.e. the pathname of the current working directory with the symbolic links resolved.

Using `df .` would give you the `df` output for whatever partition the current directory is residing on.

Example (on an OpenBSD machine):

```
$ pwd
/usr/ports
```

```
$ pwd -P
/extra/ports
```

```
$ df .
Filesystem  512-blocks      Used     Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/sd3a    103196440  55987080  42049540    57%    /extra
```

To parse out the mountpoint from this output, you may use something like

```
$ df -P . | sed -n '$s/[^%]*%[[:blank:]]*//p'
/extra
```

To parse out the filesystem device used, use

```
$ df -P . | sed -n '$s/[[:blank:]].*//p'
/dev/sd3a
```

I believe some Linux systems also supports

```
findmnt --target .
```

(where `--target .` can be replaced by `-T .`) or, for more terse output,

```
findmnt --output target --noheadings --target .
```

(where `--noheadings` may be replaced by `-n`, and `--output target` may be replaced by `-o target`) to get the mountpoint holding the filesystem that the current directory is located on.

Use `--output source` to get the mounted device node.

Comment: *"To parse out the filesystem device used, use"* ...unless you're on a system that uses ZFS, at which point that will print the ZFS file system name. So you'd get something like `tank/data/whatever/someplace` back, where `tank` is the pool name. (At that point you could map it back to a pool, and from there to a set of candidate disks, but I'm pretty sure there's no direct way to map it back to "a" disk.)

Answer (score 1):

As said by Ignacio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274354/how-to-find-out-mount-partition-a-directory-or-file-is-on-linux-server), you can use `df -P file/goes/here | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1`
.